# How can I force the name of cd-drive?

Tags: wine, games, playonlinux

How can I force the name of cd-drive? I am trying to install one game with WINE, which has three discs. It works until installation wants disk 2. Then it can't continue, because disk 2 appears as drive "game_2".

Answer (score 1):

Use `/media/cdrom` which should be symlinked to the right device.

Comment: I tried that, but /media didn't have cdrom. /media showed only name of that game disc.

Comment: In that case, possibly work around this problem by symlinking the actual game disk to /media/cdrom?  I'm not sure if that will help - just a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple things about your question that are unclear to me. First, AFAIK, the drive name should not change in linux or in wine. In linux it can be /dev/sr0, /dev/cdrom, etc... In Wine, it is a letter which you "bind" to a /dev/ in linux using wineconfig. The game is likely referring to the title of the optical media and it is apparently looking for a different disk to continue the install. Not knowing more about the specifics of your situation, I could only suggest using a virtual CD device (such as CDemu) with ISO images (in which you craft the title to be whatever you want) of the CDs/DVDs..?